# Data-driven styling for boundaries on all map types - Google Maps Javascript API V3

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3

Data-driven styling for boundaries in Google Maps Javascript API V3 is a great feature that seems like it should work on all map types (e.g. terrain, satellite, hybrid, etc...); however I can't seem to make it visible on any map type other than roadmap.

When you change the map type in [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/style-polygon) example, you are [dynamically](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#BasicMapTypes) changing the mapTypeId, which in the background is calling this function

```
map.setMapTypeId('terrain');
```

Changing between "Map" and "Satellite" will look like this

[Boundaries are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iC11R.png)

[Boundaries are not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N9iC.png)

I want to see the purple boundary layer on the satellite map as well.
So I thought, okay what if I change the default mapTypeId upon map instantiation

```
map = new Map(document.getElementById('map') as HTMLElement, {
  center: { lat: 20.773, lng: -156.01 }, // Hana, HI
  zoom: 12,
  mapId: 'a3efe1c035bad51b', // <YOUR_MAP_ID_HERE>,
  mapTypeId: "satellite" //  Thought this might work
});
```

Nope! No luck... The boundary is still only visible on the roadmap and not on the satellite map.

There must be a way to keep the data-styled boundary layer visible when changing the map type, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Currently data-driven styling for boundaries is only supported on a mapTypeId of roadmap, as per my communications with Google.